# How to update SASS for the whole of a VPS automatically?

Tags: ssl, shell, css

I have a VPS with SASS, and I have configured it correctly.

I have multiple users on my server, and they don't have SSL access to the server.

Some of them use SASS, and I don't want to have to update their files to CSS files whenever they update them.

I tried running screen, but I don't know what command to use.

How could I update the files, that are hosted on the server, constantly and automatically?

Comment: I need help guys.

Comment: Dude, you asked a question on a Sunday which is traditionally the quietest day here. You asked your question less than 20 minutes ago. We don't come with an SLA. If you want a quick response then pay someone. Whilst it may be entirely obvious to you, you'd also do well to explain what SASS is for those of us that don't know.

Answer (score 2):

This question would be much more appropriate on stackoverflow.com. BUT, if I understand correctly, I think what you need is Grunt. http://www.gruntjs.com

---

SASS also has a watch function `sass --watch style.scss:style.css`

Here you can find all of the output styles, and add them to your 'watch' command:

http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#output_style

Example: `sass --watch style.scss:style.css --style compressed`